# Show loading spinner while image is getting loaded in Foundation Clearing

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation Clearing function to show image gallery. I only load image thumbnails initially on page but on clicking those thumbnails, the Clearing image gallery opens.

But it takes a while for a large gallery image to get loaded.. Meanwhile the clearing shows nothing. So is there anyway where i can show loading notification while image is not yet loaded. Is there any inbuilt function in Foundation clearing which does that ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the loading notification for clearing, but Foundation provides one for [Orbit](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) with a `div class="preloader"`

Maybe you can hack it somehow.

Comment: Can confirm, adding a `<div class="preloader"></div>` did it for me.

Comment: Also - it's a CSS3 loader, so the colors and size is very easily customizable.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still wondering - here is how to do it in Foundation 5.5:

```
var spinDiv = document.getElementById('spinner');

$(document).on('open.fndtn.clearing', function() {
  spinDiv.style.display = 'block';
  alert('Pause so you can see the spinner');
});

$(document).on('opened.fndtn.clearing', function() {
  spinDiv.style.display = 'none';
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXXPyN